# Fetch request returns html/text instead of JSON content when launched from Nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch-api

I am launching a html webpage in my NodeJS server. On running the `server.js` file, it basically writes json data to a file, then launches the Nodejs server after 3 seconds  (so the HTML file has enough time to fetch the written data) as shown below.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
    fs.createReadStream("index.html").pipe(res);
  });
  server.listen(3000);
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:3000/`);
}, 3000);
```

But, when I fetch the `sites.json` file, the content received is HTML code in the network tab.

```
    <script>
        fetch('sites.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i];
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I tried to make http request and it worked, therefore the problem only occurs when I try to fetch json files locally.

I am not sure if this is the proper way to host a http server since it's my first time attempting this.

Comment: Your server does `fs.createReadStream("index.html").pipe(res);` for every request. You haven't done anything to make it return JSON when the browser asks for `sites.json` or, for that matter, pay any attention to what the browser is asking for.

Comment: Can you suggest how I would go about fixing it so it returns JSON?

Comment: I refer you to the duplicate question linked in the massive blue box at the top of the page.